# Cross platform C++ lib for HTML editor widget

Tags: library, c++, html-editor

I am looking for a cross-platform C++ lib that can be used as an HTML editor. It does not need to be a full HTML viewer - just an editor.
So, this would require formatting tags and fields with a different style. Color and highlight formatting. There would be a basic menu with copy/paste and style widgets.

The HTML can be rendered to a separate bitmap later.

I looked at general GUI libraries like FLTK, Qt and wxWidgets. Qt and WxWidgets are too heavy just for this application and FLTK is too basic.

Also, the C++ lib needs to allow for commercial usage and static linkage, so GPL and LGPL are excluded.

Comment: Did you try [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html)? I couldn't understand what you mean by C++ lib but Bluefish has source code there.

Comment: C++ lib needs to allow for commercial usage and static linkage, so GPL and LGPL are excluded.